# asp.net mvc 3 validation on data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to realize valition on data type. I have used DataAnnotations, but for data type it's not showing customized message

for example when I' am trying enter string data into int typed field. How I can customize messages in this case?

Comment: please show your model class and your view

Answer (score 4):

If I had to guess, you sound like you want a custom message to display when validating one or more fields in your model. You can subclass the `DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` class and override the `IsValid(object)` method and finally setting a custom `ErrorMessage` value (where `ErrorMessage` already belongs to the `ValidationAttribute` class)

```
public class SuperDuperValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        // do your validation logic here
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Finally, decorate your model property with the attribute

```
public class MyClass
{
    [SuperDuperValidator(ErrorMessage="Something is wrong with MyInt")]
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

If you're using out-of-the-box MVC3, this should be all you need to propertly validate a model (though your model will probably differ/have more properties, etc) So, in your `[HttpPost]` controller action, MVC will automagically bind `MyClass` and you will be able to use `ModelState.IsValid` to determine whether or not the posted data is, in fact, valid.

Comment: liked the validator name :) lmao

Answer (score 2):

Pavel,

The DataAnnotations DataType attribute does not affect validation. It's used to decide how your input is rendered. In such a case, David's solution above works.

However, if you want to use only the built-in validation attributes, you probably need to use the Range attribute like this:

```
[Range(0, 10, ErrorMessage="Please enter a number between 0 and 10")]
public int MyInt { get ; set ;}
```

(Of course, you should really be using the ErrorMessageResourceName/Type parameters and extract out hard-coded error message strings into resx files.)

Make sure to let MVC know where to render your error message:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyInt) %>
```

Or you can just use EditorForModel and it will set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has been answered because I have the same issue.

If you have a Model with a property of type int and the user types in a string of "asd" then the MVC3 framework binding/validation steps in and results in your view displaying `"The value 'asd' is not valid for <model property name or DisplayName here>"`.

To me the poster is asking can this message that the MVC3 framework is outputting be customized?
I'd like to know too. Whilst the message is not too bad if you label your field something that easily indicates an number is expected you might still want to include additional reasons so it says something like:

`"The value 'asd' is not valid for &lt;fieldname&gt;; must be a positive whole number."`

So that the user is not entering value after value and getting different error messages each time.